# Choose only one from 2 args with Python ArgumentParser

Tags: python, python-3.x, arguments

I use `ArgumentParser` to parse some arguments for function.

I want to limit that that user can use or `count` or `show`, he can't use then both.

How can I limit that?

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    formatter_class=argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter,
    description="""some desc""",
)

parser.add_argument(
    "count",
    nargs="?",
    type=lambda n: max(int(n, 0), 1),
    default=1,
    
)
parser.add_argument(
    "--show",
    "-s",
    action="store_true",
    default=False,
    
)
parser.add_argument(
    "--decode",
    "-d",
    action="store_true",
    default=False,
    
)
```

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#mutual-exclusion

Comment: "can use or `count` or `show`" Is word missing there? Is ``--decode`` related to this at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use mutually exclusive groups in argparse to limit the use of certain arguments.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    formatter_class=argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter,
    description="""some desc""",
)

group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
group.add_argument(
    "--show",
    "-s",
    action="store_true",
    help="Show something",
)
group.add_argument(
    "--decode",
    "-d",
    action="store_true",
    help="Decode something",
)

parser.add_argument(
    "--count",
    "-c",
    type=int,
    default=1,
    help="Count something",
)

args = parser.parse_args()
```

Answer (score 1):

The add_mutually_exclusive_group method creates a new mutually exclusive argument group. The required=True argument ensures that the user has to select one of the options in the group.

```
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)

group.add_argument(...)
group.add_argument(...)
group.add_argument(...)
```